# Cannot place ajax call within jQuery Dialog button function. Returns null

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-dialog

I need to confirm the user wants to really submit a form via a jQuery dialog button. I tried to place my ajax function inside my "Confirm" function, but it returned NULL.

How can I call the ajax function **only** if they click "Confirm"?

Here I have my dialog div:

```
echo "<div id=\"dialog_confirm\">
      <p style=\"font-size:20px; color:white;\">Are you sure you wanna do that?</p>
      <p style=\"font-size:20px; color:white;\">All records will be removed!</p>
  </div>";
```

Here I initialize my dialog

```
//Confirmation dialog
    $('#dialog_confirm').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        show: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 500
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "fade",
            duration: 500
        },
        buttons: {
            "Confirm": function () { //Tried to place my ajax function
                                     //here but it returned null
                $(this).dialog('close');
                $('#remove_domain_form')[0].reset();
            },
            "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
```

My form submit function:

```
 $('#remove_domain_form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var isEmpty = false;
    $(':input:not(button)').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() === "") {
            var error_text = $('#dialog p').text("All fields are required");
            $('#dialog').html(error_text);
            $('#dialog').dialog('option', 'title', 'Error').dialog('open');
            isEmpty = true;
        }
        else {
            $('#dialog_confirm').dialog('open');
        }
    });
    if (!isEmpty) {
        // <------ I NEED TO HAVE THE CONFIRMATION DIALOG HERE
        console.log("Not Empty");
        $.ajax({
            url: "check-domain-remove.php",
            type: "post",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $('#remove_domain_form').serialize(),
            success: function (response) {
                if (response === "Success") {
                    //DO OTHER STUFF
                    var success_div = '<p class=\"input--success\">Domain Successfully Removed</p><br><br>';
                    $('body').append(success_div);
                }
            }

        });
    }
});
```

**Edit**: I also tried to place it in a function that fires on the close/Confirm event, still to no avail. If I click "Confirm," it returns null. If I click "Cancel," I get the correct results! This is so strange, and I don't know why it is happening.

```
$('#dialog_confirm').bind('dialogclose', function(event, ui) {
        if($(event.target).text() != 'Cancel') {
            console.log("Clicked Confirm");
            $.ajax({
                url: "check-domain-remove.php",
                type: "post",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: $('#remove_domain_form').serialize(),
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response === "Success") {
                        //DO OTHER STUFF
                        var success_div = '<p class=\"input--success\">Domain Successfully Removed</p><br><br>';
                        $('body').append(success_div);
                    }
                }

            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: So you have a button, which if they click opens a modal that the user then needs to click confirm to submit the form?

Comment: Why not have a return false; statement in your loop to stop the script and remove the if statement you have afterwards and just use your ajax request, so that if it passes validation, it'll just run the ajax

Comment: @Keith - Yes, it's supposed to submit on Confirm.

Comment: Is #remove_domain_form the first button or the confirm button?

Comment: #remove_domain_form is the initial form button, which then bring up the confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

This might have something to do with the element not being present when jQuery is loaded. Try changing your code to this:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#remove_domain_form', function (e) {...})
```

Comment: See my update. I tried to bind it to the close event, and it works, but with the "Cancel" button instead of the "Confirm" button. And doesn't the .submit() function do the same thing as your code?

Comment: Hmm, that is pretty strange. The reason I wrote my above comment was because it has worked for me many times in the past and on a consistent basis. .submit(), .click(), etc does work but I have found that for dynamically created elements, they don't seem to work. In the code I wrote, it attaches the listener on the dynamically created element.

Answer (score 0):

OK so do this:

```
$('#yourFirstButton').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(':input:not(button)').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() === "") {
            var error_text = $('#dialog p').text("All fields are required");
            $('#dialog').html(error_text);
            $('#dialog').dialog('option', 'title', 'Error').dialog('open');
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $('#dialog_confirm').dialog('open');
        }
    });        
});

$('#yourConfirmButton').on('click', function(){
    $('#remove_domain_form').submit(
        // <------ I NEED TO HAVE THE CONFIRMATION DIALOG HERE
        console.log("Not Empty");
        $.ajax({
            url: "check-domain-remove.php",
            type: "post",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $('#remove_domain_form').serialize(),
            success: function (response) {
                if (response === "Success") {
                    //DO OTHER STUFF
                    var success_div = '<p class=\"input--success\">Domain Successfully Removed</p><br><br>';
                    $('body').append(success_div);
                }
            }    
        });
    )
});
```

So the validation breaks at return false and then proceeds with the ajax call afterwards if it passes.

Comment: I tried that, and it's now submitting the form anyway, then giving me the confirmation dialog. It's not returning null now, however.

Comment: Is #remove_domain_form the confirm button?

Comment: Updated with new code to have the form submit on the confirm button

Comment: Created id for button, edited code, and got "Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined"

Comment: when you debug it, what line does that error occur on

Comment: Couldn't tell you now. The rest of the code has been added and the bug was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. I needed (for some reason I don't yet know) to add empty click functions in my dialog initialization. I am now able to submit the form and get the dialog. If I click Cancel, it closes. If I click Confirm, the ajax returns what I need.

Keith, your suggestion to create the click function was almost what I needed. I just needed to add the click functions.

```
$('#dialog_confirm').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        show: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 500
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "fade",
            duration: 500
        },
        buttons: {
            'Confirm' : {
                text:'Confirm',
                id:'confirm_button',
                click:function() {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            },
            'Cancel' : {
                text:'Cancel',
                id:'cancel_button',
                click:function() {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        }
    });

$('#remove_domain_form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //var isEmpty = false;
    $(':input:not(button)').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() === "") {
            var error_text = $('#dialog p').text("All fields are required");
            $('#dialog').html(error_text);
            $('#dialog').dialog('option', 'title', 'Error').dialog('open');
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $('#dialog_confirm').dialog('open');
        }
    });

    $('#confirm_button').click(function() {
        console.log("Not Empty");
        $.ajax({
            url: "check-domain-remove.php",
            type: "post",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $('#remove_domain_form').serialize(),
            success: function (response) {
                if (response === "Success") {
                    //DO OTHER STUFF
                    var success_div = '<p class=\"input--success\">Domain Successfully Removed</p><br><br>';
                    $('body').append(success_div);
                }
            }

        });
    });
});
```